# Реализация std::atomic::exchange

Tags: c++, многопоточность, ассемблер, синхронизация, атомарность

Недавно начал изучать атомики, решил посмотреть дизассемблированный код std::atomic::exchange:

c++

```
int exchange(int i) {
    return atom.exchange(i);
}
```

Asm x86-64 clang 14.0.0

```
exchange(int):                           # @exchange(int)
        mov     eax, edi
        xchg    dword ptr [rip + atom], eax
        ret
```

Не понимаю почему такая реализация будет атомарной, ведь, если несколько потоков зайдут в atom.exchange() и выполнят первую инструкцию(mov), то тогда "старые" значения edi затрутся.

Comment: А разве регистры у каждого потока не своим собственные? Это только память общая.

Comment: Спасибо(я не знал что у каждого потока свои регистры), но тогда вопрос: почему реализация использует mov + xchg? почему не сделать ее просто через два mov?

Comment: `почему реализация использует mov + xchg?` - потому что `xchg` с операндом в памяти по сути и является атомарной инструкцией, а `mov` не атомарна по своей природе.

Comment: То есть даже если мы используем mov для двух регистров (mov     eax, edi), то это будет не атомарно?

Comment: В общем, видимо понял, в первой строке mov атомарный, потому что работает с двумя регистрами, xchg атомарен по определению и нужен для атомарной работы с операндом в памяти, а вместе обе инструкции работают атомарно, потому что у каждого потока свои регистры.

Comment: `то это будет не атомарно?` - пересылка данных `mov` между двумя регистрами не является атомарной. Если у вас несколько потоков, то именно для таких случаев предусмотрены объекты синхронизации типа ивенты/семафоры. То-есть первый поток должен сообщать второму, что данные освободились и готовы к последующим операциям. Как-правило сигналы передаются при помощи функции `WaitForSingleObject()`.